# Possible values of a function involving random variable

Tags: probability

> Let $\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be i.i.d. random variable with $0 < Var(\xi_i) < \infty$. Find all possible values of the function 
>   $$
> \varphi(x)
>  = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i < x\right],
> \quad x\in \mathbb{R}.
> $$

**My thoughts:** If $x < \min(\xi_i)$, then $\varphi(x)=0$. If $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i$ converges and $x > \sup(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i)$, then $\varphi(x)=1$. What are other possibilities?

Comment: Somebody please argue with me, is this line of thinking below correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that (from Central Limit Theorem) the quantity $\sqrt{n}(S_n-\mu)$ where $S_n = \frac{\xi_1+\xi_2+\cdots\xi_n}{n}$ and $\mu,\sigma^2$ bening the average and variance of each $\xi_i$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$ almost surely converges to $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ (Gaussian variable with zero mean and variance equal to $\sigma^2$). Therefore

$$\mathbb{P}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i < x\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i }{\sqrt{n}} - \mu\sqrt{n} < \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}-\mu\sqrt{n}\right]$$

Now if we assume $\mu > 0$ and taking the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get

$$\mathbb{P}\left[y < -\infty\right] = 0$$

Where $y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. on the other hand if $\mu < 0$ then we have

$$\mathbb{P}\left[y < \infty\right] = 1$$

and if $\mu=0$ we have
$$\mathbb{P}\left[y < 0\right] = \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus $\varphi(x)$ is a constant function and its value is dependent on $\mu$, either of $\{0,1,\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Comment: This is different, because the sum in the question is not divided by $n$.

Comment: Is that important? The left hand side may diverges? The probability that is calculated is the same as the quantity that is wanted though. How not being divided by $n$ affects the calculation? Would you please elaborate. Also do you have alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Paul This is not different at all. The first equality is identity.